# Input validation exclusive or

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I have a model called Answer.

This model has two possible relations. A `Question` or a `Product`.
But, Answer should only ever have one relation. Either Question or Product.

There is a form to create answers.

This form has three inputs. two of them are `<select>` inputs. The other is a text input, called name.

I want my validation to only allow one  to be filled out.

My current validation:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    array('name' => array('required'))
);

$validator->sometimes('product', array('required', 'numeric'), function ($input) {
    return !is_numeric($input->question);
});

$validator->sometimes('question', array('required', 'numeric'), function ($input) {
    return !is_numeric($input->product);
});
```

Requires at least one of the selected to be filled out, but will also allow two.

So, my question is: How can I change my validation to only allow one of the selects to be filled out.
But one of them must always be filled out.

**Select 1:**

```
<select name="question" class="form-control">
    <option>None</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Question 1</option>
    <option value="2">Question 2</option>
</select>
```

**Select 2:**

```
<select name="product" class="form-control">
    <option>None</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Product 1</option>
    <option value="3">Product 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off. You must specify an empty value in "None" option:

```
<option value=''>None</option>
```

---

You are looking for [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator, you need to create a custom validation rule in this case:

```
Validator::extendImplicit('xor', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    if( $value XOR app('request')->get($parameters[0]))
        return true;
    return false;
});
Validator::replacer('xor', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    // add indefinite articles
    $IAattribute = (stristr('aeiou', $attribute[0]) ? 'an ' : 'a ') . $attribute;
    $parameters[0] = (stristr('aeiou', $parameters[0][0]) ? 'an ' : 'a ') . $parameters[0];

    if(app('request')->get($attribute))
        return 'You cannot choose both '.$IAattribute.' and '.$parameters[0].'.';
    return $IAattribute.' or '.$parameters[0].' is required.';
});


$validator = Validator::make(
    app('request')->all(),
    array('name' => array('required')
    ,'product' => array('xor:question')
));
```

Comment: The logic in the first closure (aka. anonymous function) can be merged and reduced. I have edited your answer accordingly. Also maybe consider using "new" array style `[]`.

Answer (score 5):

@Razor's custom XOR validation rule is pretty nice, but there's another route if you don't want to create a custom rule. You can add values to `Input` representing your constraints, using `Input::merge`, then use those for validation:

```
Input::merge(array(
    'hasBoth'    => Input::has('product')  && Input::has('question'),
    'hasNeither' => !Input::has('product') && !Input::has('question')
));

$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(), array(
        'name'       => 'required',
        'hasNeither' => 'size:0',
        'hasBoth'    => 'size:0',
    ), array(
        'hasNeither.size' => 'A question or a product is required.',
        'hasBoth.size'    => 'You cannot choose both a question and a product.'         
    )
);
```

You should still change the empty value in your form to `<option value=''>None</option>`.

Unlike using an XOR comparison, this method allows you to return separate error messages for *no values* vs. *two values* without any further error checking.

Comment: pretty good workaround, I like it. However, it's not reusable. Also, with XOR comparison, you can return separate error messages, check my edit ( I get your messages :p ). If @CharliePrynn doesn't need to reuse this logic in other forms, then probably your answer is the best.

Comment: Yes, it's not easily reusable if there's a need for that. If reusability was necessary, though, I think it would make sense to abstract the same logic—grouping inputs together and testing for the existence of all of them or none of them—into a custom validator class. I could envision a construct like `'group'=>'hasAll:product,question,other'` and `'group'=>'hasNone:product,question,other'` that would handle the logic in the `Input::merge` part. That way, you could still easily test both conditions independently, and could also set custom error messages for each condition independently.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, it would be great to extend the Validator class to include "has" functionality, which would accept an array or list of fields and then validate them as a group, like: `'product,question,other' => 'hasMoreThan:0'` or `'hasLessThen:2'`/`'hasBetween:0,2'`/`'has:all'`/`'has:none'`/`'has:5'`, etc. Then you could have full control over error messages, and the logic would be reusable for any number of fields. In @CharliePrynn's case, you would run `'product,question' => 'hasMoreThan:0|hasLessThan:2'` and be able to return separate error messages for each condition.

Answer (score 2):

Answers are a little old now. Today laravel brings some prohibition-rules which will resolve your problems without any hacks.

For your validation that means:

```
return [
   'question' => 'nullable|required_without:product',
   'product' => ['nullable', 
        Rule::prohibitedIf(fn() => $this->question != '')]
```

Both selects need an item with empty-value, with a text/label you like. Like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="">Foo</option>
</select>
```

Like this one of the both always need to be set. But its not possible that both are set.

See here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibited

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the concrete solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The `required_without` [validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#available-validation-rules) might be what you want:

> The field under validation must be present only when any of the other
>   specified fields are not present.

Set the `question` field to `required_without:product` and the `product` field to `required_without:question`.

Comment: This will make the validation work similar to how it does currently. Meaning a user can still select both and the validation will pass. I could have extra logic in the controller to handle this and select one, but I don't really want to take that approach. I'd prefer if I could find a way for the validation to handle it.